# NFSv4 with autofs automount hanging only for some users

Tags: linux, nfs, autofs, nfs4

I have a DRBD partition mounted get auto-mounted using Linux-HA, then it sets up a bind and shares the directory via NFS. This shares out a directory for user home directories.

Some users work fine, most do not and it sits there hanging on mounting their folder. When I do a tcpdump I see:

```
07:45:16.415649 IP foo.server.com.1002 > nfs.server.com.nfs: . ack 976 win 348
07:45:22.705531 IP foo.server.c.2174542926 > nfs.server.com.nfs: 192 getattr [|nfs]
07:45:22.705643 IP nfs.server.com.nfs > foo.server.com.1002: . ack 1985 win 501
07:45:23.703517 IP nfs.server.com.nfs > foo.server.c.2174542926: reply ok 96 getattr ERROR: Request couldn't be completed in time
07:45:23.703564 IP foo.server.com.1002 > nfs.server.com.nfs: . ack 1072 win 348
07:45:25.053519 IP foo.server.c.2191320142 > nfs.server.com.nfs: 192 getattr [|nfs]
07:45:25.053651 IP nfs.server.com.nfs > foo.server.com.1002: . ack 2177 win 501
07:45:26.051473 IP nfs.server.com.nfs > foo.server.c.2191320142: reply ok 96 getattr ERROR: Request couldn't be completed in time
07:45:26.051522 IP foo.server.com.1002 > nfs.server.com.nfs: . ack 1168 win 348
07:45:31.413431 IP foo.server.c.2208097358 > nfs.server.com.nfs: 160 getattr [|nfs]
07:45:31.413556 IP nfs.server.com.nfs > foo.server.com.1002: . ack 2337 win 501
07:45:32.411393 IP nfs.server.com.nfs > foo.server.c.2208097358: reply ok 76 getattr ERROR: Request couldn't be completed in time
```

my auto.master looks like:

```
/home/users   /etc/auto.home  --timeout=60
```

my auto.home :

```
*       -fstype=nfs4,rw,nosuid,soft,rsize=8192,wsize=8192  nfs.server.com:/home/&
```

my exports :

```
/nfs4exports 192.168.0.0/255.255.0.0(rw,no_subtree_check,nohide,no_root_squash,fsid=0)
/nfs4exports/home 192.168.0.0/255.255.0.0(rw,no_subtree_check,nohide,no_root_squash)
```

my idmapd.conf :

```
[General]

Verbosity = 0
Pipefs-Directory = /var/lib/nfs/rpc_pipefs
Domain = bb.int.threatmetrix.com

[Mapping]

Nobody-User = nfsnobody
Nobody-Group = nfsnobody

[Translation]
Method = nsswitch
```

I'm using CentOS 5.4, nfs versions:

nfs-utils-1.0.9-42.el5
nfs-utils-lib-1.0.8-7.6.el5
nfs4-acl-tools-0.3.3-1.el5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this turned out to be the clue:

```
rpc.idmapd[5924]: nfsdcb: id '-2' too big!
```

the issue was that the default nfsnobody user has a uid of 4294967294 , but on a 64-bit CentOS system it appears to be interpreting this number in a 32-bit context leading to the infamous -2. The fix is to :

- change nfsnobody user/group to uid/gid 65534 on *both client and server*
- chown any files owned by uid 4294967294 on the server to nfsnobody

this resolves the issue

Comment: I find it ridiculous that Linux distributions didn't just, when they first started making a 64-bit flavor, declare that nfsnobody is 65534 regardless of architecture.